# Power BI DAX code to get Get Maximum and Minimum Date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 2 measures that calculate the maximum profit and minimum profit.

```
Maximum Profit = Maxx(ALLSELECTED(Dates),[Profit running total in Date])
```

and

```
Minimum Profit = MINX(ALLSELECTED(Dates),[Profit running total in Date])
```

The following is the DAX that I used to calculate total of running profit.

```
Profit running total in Date = CALCULATE( [Profit],FILTER(ALLSELECTED('Dates'[Date]),ISONORAFTER('Dates'[Date], MAX('Dates'[Date]), DESC)))
```

I am now trying to show the dates that the maximum profit and minimum profit occurred. My coding skills are miserable. Can someone point me in the right direction. TIA

Edit:
Further to the above I have tried to code but with miserable success. As an example I have tried this as a code

```
MaxDate = If([Profit running total in Date] = FILTER(ALLSELECTED('Dates'[Date]),ISONORAFTER('Dates'[Date], MAX('Dates'[Date]), DESC)),MAX('Dates'[Date]))
```

This throws up an error of

> MdxScript(Model) (437, 65) Calculation error in measure 'Report'[MaxDate]: A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to an answer as follows:

```
Max Profit Date = MAXX(FILTER(ALLSELECTED(Dates), [Profit running total in Date] = [Maximum Profit]), Dates[Date])
```

and

```
Min Profit Date = MAXX(FILTER(ALLSELECTED(Dates), [Profit running total in Date] = [Minimum Profit]), Dates[Date])
```